# WordPress custom related posts using Ad Inserter

Tags: wordpress

The below code is what I'm using to grab related posts.
It works great, some of the time. Other times it appears to mess with the permalinks of buttons, e.g. via the archives blog posts.

Since this is a very simple code block, I thought I'd post the entire program in the hope someone can point out something I'm doing wrong.

```
<?php
$categoryArray = get_the_category();
//print("<pre>" . print_r($categories,true) . "</pre>");

// $categoryArray[0] is an object and must first
// be converted to get values
$catId = get_object_vars($categoryArray[0])['cat_ID'];

// get the post id.
$postId = get_the_ID();

// description of args and how to use them;
// https://gist.github.com/luetkemj/2023628
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'cat' => $catId,
  'post__not_in' => array($postId),
);

$loop = new wp_Query($args);

$related_posts_are_available = false;

while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
  if ($related_posts_are_available == false) {
    echo '<h3 style="margin-top:50px; margin-bottom:15px">Related Posts</h3>';
    echo '<ul>';

    $related_posts_are_available = true;
  };

  echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';

  //the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );
  the_title( '<div style="font-size:105%">', '</div>' );

  echo '</a></li>';
endwhile;

if ($related_posts_are_available == true) {
  echo '</ul>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Is it possible I'm using a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running this code? What file? You are using very generic variable names for what I believe to be custom code, maybe you are accidentally overwriting something.

Comment: inside of an ad inserter block, which is a wordpress plugin

Comment: ok, like I said, I would start by giving all variables (everything that starts with a $) in your script a custom prefix.
Like $postId becomes $KS_postId,
$args becomes $KS_args,
etc